# Mark descriptor as terminal for the -t test

Tags: terminal, zsh, pipe, file-descriptors, terminal-multiplexer

One can test if a descriptor is connected to terminal with -t test.

```
if [ ! -t 0 ]; then
    echo "Stdin is not from terminal"
fi
```

Having a descriptor X, pointing to a file or to a process (with >(cmd) redirection), is it possible to make it look like terminal? For the test -t to pass?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `>(cmd)`, assuming it's `cmd`'s stdin you wish be a tty instead of a pipe, you could try and use:

```
>(socat -u - exec:'cmd',pty)
```

`socat` would use a pseudo-tty pair and have `cmd`'s stdin connected to the slave part (`[ -t 0 ]` would then return true).

The pseudo-terminal will be put in raw mode, so the line discipline should not interfere with the data so in that regard it's more or less equivalent to a pipe.

However, pseudo-terminals can't be closed on one end only like pipes do. So, `socat` can't tell `cmd` that there's no more input. Instead, after `socat`'s stdin reaches end-of-file, `socat` will wait a bit and destroy the pseudo-tty which generally means `cmd` getting a SIGHUP.

If your command takes longer to process the data, or waits for end-of-file on stdin before starting doing anything, that won't work properly.

Comment: After issuing: `exec > >(socat -u - exec:'cat',pty)` the following outputs `noterminal`: `[ -t 1 ] && echo terminal || echo noterminal`

Comment: @OneOther, it's `cat` that has its stdin as a terminal. `>(...)` expands to the path of a pipe, always, there's no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

The `test` command runs `isatty(fd)` to check whether a descriptor is related to a TTY.

`isatty(3)` is a C library function that checks whether a file descriptor allows to send terminal `ioctl(2)` calls to the descriptor.

You therefore cannot fake the result unless you use `LD_PRELOAD=` to overwrite the `isatty()` function in the shell.